# Problems upgrading Laravel 5.4 to 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm using Laravel Framework 5.4.32, and after following the instructions in the two upgrade guides for [5.5.0 From 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade), and [5.6.0 From 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade), and the consensus that it's safe to do an upgrade for both in one go, I went ahead with a `composer upgrade`, got a list of problems but no guidance on how to fix them:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager ^0.11.14 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v0.11.14].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - tcg/voyager v0.11.14 requires illuminate/support ~5.3.0|~5.4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36], illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.4.36].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.2
0, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
```

When I ran `php artisan --version` afterwards, I got an error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Call to
>   undefined method App\Console\Kernel::load()

So something's changed, although the application continues to work.

Aside from adding `$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');` to the "commands()" method in "Kernel.php", the main changes were in "composer.json", as advised in the two upgrade guides.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcg/voyager package is the problem

```
tcg/voyager v0.11.14 requires illuminate/support ~5.3.0|~5.4.0
```

You're installing 5.6 but it needs 5.4.

Upgrade it to version 1.1

Comment: I've seen that, but the main problem appears to be Laravel itself; I am using 5.4. I've undone the changes to `composer.json`, and ran `composer update` on the original file, and I think that's what needed to be done first, though I'm still tinkering.

Comment: It's not a laravel problem, it's the Voyager version being v0.11.14. Change it to 1.1 and composer should run without issue.

Comment: Voyager requires Laravel 5.4 and I'm using 5.4.32.

Comment: Yes, you've since rolled back to 5.4. The logs in your post show 5.6. I'm saying update the voyager package version in composer.json and go back to upgrading laravel.

Comment: What I don't understand is how /upgrading/ a package on a previous version of Laravel would help in the process of upgrading Laravel itself. That aside, it's working, so thank you.

Comment: It's how composer ensures that every package installed will work and not break your application when major version changes occur. You'll see for that version of voyager its maximum compatibility with laravel is 5.4. So by bumping voyager to the latest version and then upgrading laravel, you dont have the conflicts since v1.1 is compatible with 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the Requirement in official website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade)

Comment: I have done, as explained in: "... after following the instructions in the two upgrade guides for 5.5.0 From 5.4, and 5.6.0 From 5.5"